# Qt inputMethodEvent - get the keyboard key that was pressed?

Tags: c++, qt, input, globalization, ime

I'm creating an app with Qt but using custom text edits through DirectX. In order to receive Chinese/Korean/Japanese input in the textEdits I've enabled `WA_inputMethodEnabled` on the custom widget that controls DirectX.

The only issue is that now when my keyboard is set to any of these languages, all of the events passed in are `QInputMethodEvents` whether or not I'm editing text. So I'm not receiving any `QKeyEvents` which I need to handle some shortcut keys.

The events are being passed through an event filter.

**My Question:** is there a way to get which physical key press triggered the `QInputMethodEvent`?

Alternatively, with the IME active if you click in the bottom right icon in the windows taskbar you can switch between english/the other language. Is there a way to do this through Qt? That way I can just switch between them when the text edit is active/inactive.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps your input widget implementation doesn't properly interact with the text input system. There's a bit more to that than merely reimplementing a `QWidget`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite see what you're getting at. The issue is that with the IME active, all keyPress events are replaced with QInputMethodEvents.

Comment: The widget has to interoperate with IME to turn it off as needed, etc. Does your widget, at the very least, manage its focus properly?

Comment: The text edit is not a QWidget. It's a custom structure rendered with directX. It, as well as the 3D scene, is rendered within a DXWidget. So it technically always has focus. Is there a way to turn off IME manually through the code?

Comment: That's your problem. You can render things with whatever you want, but you do need a `QWidget` wrapper to manage input contexts, focus, etc., if you want to interoperate with rest of Qt.